# PHP check if the function returns boolean

Tags: php

So I got this function:

```
function hosting(){
    $localhostIP = array(
        '127.0.0.1',
        '::1'
    );
    if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $localhostIP)){
        $localhost = false;
        return true;
    }else{
        $localhost = true;
        return $localhost;
    }
}
```

Later in the same file I want to call the function and check if the $localhost is true or false, this is what I got so far:

```
hosting();
if ($localhost == false) {
    echo"N";
}else{
   echo"Y";
}
```

It doesn't work and it is probably worst attempt ever, could someone show me how to check $localhost in the right way?

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: did you try `$localhost = hosting()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [assign the return value from the function call to a variable](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php):

```
$localhost = hosting();
if ($localhost == false) {
    echo"N";
}else{
   echo"Y";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine now. Just one more question how can I check if the function is true or false if its written like this:function hosting(){
 $localhostIP = array(
  '127.0.0.1',
     '::1'
 );
 if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $localhostIP)){
     return true;
 }else{
  return false;
 }
}

Comment: Your question does not make any sense. Your code *exactly* what you're aksing.

Comment: Sorry, here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/26f2321d3342680ab7603f30f483f59538f7f220 this time there is no $localhost, just {return true;}. How can I check that? Edit: Link works fine now

Answer (score 0):

A better approach may be;

```
function isLocalhost($ipAddress) {
    $localhostIP = array(
        '127.0.0.1',
        '::1'
    );

    return in_array($ipAddress, $localhostIP);
}

//To check whether the request coming from localhost or not

if(isLocalhost($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
   echo "Localhost";
} else {
   echo "Not Localhost";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, looks like much better solution!